# Likelihood function of two (probably) independent variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The energy consumption (with the proper units) of a city is normally distributed with $\mu=100$ and $\sigma=1$. After $\theta$ days another factory began to operate with unit consumption. What is the likelihood function for $x_1,\dots,x_n$ observations?

I think I should write down the joint probability of the consumption of the city and the consumption of the new factory, which I think has Poisson distribution with parameter $\theta$. But I'm not sure about that part. How should I interpret mathematically that the new factory began to operate after $\theta$ days?

Comment: It says the factory has unit consumption which suggests to me that they use exactly one unit. So on day $\theta$ the mean shifts to $101$ and the variance stays the same.

Comment: But how should I incorporate $\theta$ into the distribution function?

Comment: The joint distribution function / likelihood will have the first $\theta$ factors (i.e. the factors for for $x_1\ldots x_\theta$) look like $e^{-(x_i-100)^2/2}$ and the last $n-\theta$ factors look the same except the 100 is replaced by $101.$

Comment: I get it now, thank you!